# cant keep basic cloud code function to work using parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am unable to get basic cloud code functions working using Parse.com. I want to keep main.js as clean as possible, and also want to attach functions to HTML buttons and keep that process clean and easy to use. My solution was to only use main.js for cloud code definition, and use another file(app.js) to house my functions that would call the cloud code and house my non cloud code functions. For some reason I get errors when using require, it wont recognize Parse.Cloud.Define, to name a few problems. I have reduced my code down to the simplest function possible and I still cant get it to work. I am getting so frustrated with Parse. I had my code working locally but when I tried converting it to cloud code on Parse I have run into so many problems, can I please get some help to atleast get me through this hurdle. Ill post all of my code below. The error I am getting is that require is causing an error that says require is undefined. Whats even more annoying is that if I look at the logs on Parse.com the function runs and Hello World! is properly logged. This is causing the function to not run correctly in the browser though(this function runs but others ive been testing dont). Can I get any help as to why require is causing errors on such a simple set of code? Thanks in advance

main.js

```
Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx"); // xxxx is just to hide my ID.
require('cloud/app.js');

Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

app.js

```
function callHello(){
    Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
        success: function(result){              
        },
        error: function(error){             
        }
    });
}
```

HTML page running the callHello() function

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="IT Ticket System">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IT Ticket Request</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="../cloud/main.js"></script>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="../cloud/app.js"></script>
</head>
  <body> <br>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
    <div class="inputForm">
      <br><br>
      <h1>Login</h1><br><br>

         <button type="button" onclick="callHello()">test</button> 
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript files (main.js) for your cloud code should be uploaded to parse, they live and are executed in the parse container in the cloud.

Your javascript in your web page should be using the Parse JS SDK to call the specified parse cloud function and handle the response. It can't directly import the parse cloud code JS.

So your app.js file looks fine to use directly but your main.js file needs to be uploaded and not included in your web page.

Comment: by uploaded do you mean deploy? Both of these are in the cloud folder, so when i deploy it they both are in the cloud code. I verified that by going to my cloud code section in my parse web dashboard. Am i always going to get those errors because IE debugger doesnt know what to do with parse elements? Why is require('cloud\app.js'); throwing out an error?

Comment: Yes, deploy. So you need to separate your files, you can't treat all of them the same way, some are cloud and some are client. I guess if you included libraries you could get it to not throw an error, but it still wouldn't be correct.

Comment: I have both of them in the cloud folder and deploy both because when I had that app.js file in another folder(in a folder called public at the same level as the cloud folder), it couldnt find that file. By looking at the program run in debugger mode, i noticed it hung at the first place that made a call to a function in that file. The only way I could get it to run or do anything was to get both files in cloud code. Require wouldnt work there either.

Comment: Require does work in the cloud but it's used to load a files declared services into a var so you can use them later.nyhere is a set export syntax for that. It seems that you need to get your server and client code separated before you correct that syntax. See https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-modules